# Updating an app in the Windows Phone Store

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-store

Can someone clarify how do I create an update in the Windows Phone Store? I'm confused on how to get this to work.

In the lifecycle section, I've got the option to "add a new file" or replace the existing one.

If I select "add a new" file, I need to re-specify all the information for the file all over again i.e. version, keywords, description, changes, etc...

If I select "replace" file, it does just that but I don't get notified that an update is available and when I go to the store, it doesn't give me the option to update, which means that I first have to uninstall the app and then install it again.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, say if you already have a WP8 app in store, and you are adding a WP8.1 version, You need to choose **add new** to upload the new appx file to store.

If you simply want to update your existing WP8 xap, you need to select **replace** instead.

When you are done with the change, click the **Save** button at the bottom of the page. And after you will need to click **Review and Submit**, followed by a final **Submit** button.

After all this, you will need to wait for Microsoft to send you an email saying either it's certified or rejected. They used to send out an email right after you submitted something, they don't do it anymore.

The good thing is that the certification process now takes much less time than before. I just submitted my last update and it got certified within 15 minutes.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the clarification but that's what I've been doing I.e replace, but I've yet to be prompted/notified to update my app when there is an update for it. The only option I get when going to the store is View, rather than Update.

Comment: It's most likely because the version you see in store is cached. If you have WP8.1 installed, go to Store -> Settings, click the button Check for updates. This will ignore the cache and (if the update is indeed available) download all the updates.

Comment: I've just uploaded a new version of my app and did what you suggested and it worked. Thanks @Xin.

Comment: Could you tell me please, how to change the name of an when updating ? The name field in App info is disabled ! Thank you.